# SSRS - displaying two datasets on the same chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I've got a chart which is displaying information from one dataset as a scatter chart, representing sales vs date. This displays fine.

However, I've also got a second dataset. This is working out a trendline, and also needs to be displayed over the top of the chart.

Unfortunately, whenever I try it comes up with the "data must be aggregated" bit and, if I do aggregate the second dataset, it only comes up with a single point (there should be two).

Should also mention that I doubt I can combine the two datasets as the date range for the trendline one may extend far beyond that of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - managed to get it working by putting it in the same dataset using a union query.